# Surrounding text with a method call

Tags: php, templates, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I have a class that has two methods that are used often:`self::foo()` and `self::bar()`.

I would like to surround text, mainly variables in other methods. I can do comments, `if/else`, `try/catch`, etc, but I can't with arbitrary method calls.

I don't even know if PHPStorm does this, honestly. Does anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE**

I would like to take this:

```
function func() {
    return $variable;
}
```

and make it this:

```
function func() {
    return self::foo($variable);
}
```

or

```
function func() {
    return this->bar($variable);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and use **Live Template** that will do what you want (surround current selection with predefined template): separate template for each method call.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program -- the last section "Creating Surround Templates" is what you need in particular.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had the Live Templates, but I didn't see any documentation about `$SELECTION$`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a function using WebStorm's refactoring tools.

Do do so, mark the code you want to have extracted and press Ctrl + Alt + M.

For more info, have a look at JetBrains' Website:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/05/extract-function-method-refactoring-for-php/

**Edit:** Thanks for the clarification. I am not aware of a refactoring tool that fulfills this particular need. However, if you have a lot of occurrences in one file, [Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't need to extract a function, so I updated my question for clarity.

Comment: Search and replace is a good idea. I`ll see what I can do with it. Thanks.